# CSS/HTML positioning - Elements Overlay content

Tags: css, position, overlay, alignment, absolute

Forgive me if my question is stupid, but I'm not a web programmer and I've spend the past 2 hours trying to figure this out.

So, I am using Weebly for my website, and there is a "content" area where I can place elements. Then to the right and left of the "content" area, I want to place ads.

I've figured out how to do this using absolute positioning, and it looks fine on a computer's browser, but on Mobile (Regardless of user agent used), the google adsense ads overlay my content area.

Here is what I want it to look like:

<del>http://testing.jakaar.net/</del>    (this website is no longer in existence.

**EDIT:** http://android.jakaar.net/index.html  (this is my website, and it works now, see below for the answer to my issue).

<del>But, that does NOT work on a mobile phone. The ads still show, they just overlay.</del>
**EDIT:** It works now, see my answer below.

I tried using position:relative in my css to position the ads to the left and right, but then they are either above or below my content area, so it pushes everything up or down.

Here is the CSS that I think is relevant:

```
body {
    background: url(bodybg.jpg) top repeat-x;
    background-color:#efefef;
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    font-size:12px;
    color:#666666;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

#content{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width: 898px;
    background: #fff;
    min-height: 500px;
    _height: 500px;
    padding: 32px;
}
```

Then for the HTML:

```
<head>
<title>{title}</title>
<style type="text/css">
.right
{
position:absolute;
right:0px;
padding-right:80px;
padding-left:80px;
margin-top:180px;
}
.left
{


   position:absolute;
    left:0px;
    padding-right:80px;
    padding-left:80px;
    margin-top:180px;
    }
    </style>


        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="header">
                <div id="headerleft">{logo max-height="60"}</div>
                <div id="navigation">{menu}</div>
             </div>

            <div class="right">
    //adsense add that goes on the right
    </div>
    <div class="left">
    //adsense add that goes on the left
    </div>
<div id="content">
        {content}
        </div>

        <div id="footer">{footer}</div>
    </div>
```

I've also tried using `float:left` and `float:right`, but it gave the same behavior as the absolute positioning.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a 3 column layout, and placed my ads in column 1 and column 3 then placed the "Content" in column 2. I used http://webdesign.about.com/od/csstutorials/ss/css_layout_sbs_9.htm for a tutorial.

<del>I also used `position:fixed` for my ads so they scroll with the page.</del>
That caused formatting issues that I don't feel like fixing right now, so I removed the fixed positioning.

The result is here: http://android.jakaar.net/index.html

Here is the relevant CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 1402px;
    margin: 0 0 0 20px; 
    padding: 0;
}
#wrapper #topad
{
margin-top:20px;
margin-bottom:20px;
}
#wrapper #col1 
{ 
width: 190px;
float: left; 
margin-top: 230px;
} 
#col1 #leftad
{
float:right;
position:fixed;
width:160px;
}
#wrapper #col2outer 
{
width: 1202px;
float: right; 
margin: 0; 
padding: 0; 
} 
#col2outer #col2mid 
{ 
width: 962px; 
float: left;
} 
#col2outer #col2side 
{ 
margin-top: 230px;
width: 190px;
float: right; 
}
#col2side #rightad
{
position:fixed;
width:160px;
}
```

And the relevant HTML:

```
<body>
<center><!--I used this to enclose the entire body because otherwise everything was off-center, of course-->
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="col1">
        <div id="leftad">
        <!--google adsense ad code-->
        </div>
        </div>

        <div id="col2outer">
        <div id="col2mid">
        <div id="header">
            <div id="headerleft">{logo max-height="60"}</div>
            <div id="navigation">{menu}</div>
            </div>
            <div id="topad">
            <!--google adsense ad code-->
        </div>

        <div id="content">
          {content}
          </div>
          </div><!--this is the close of "col2mid"-->

          <div id="col2side"> 
          <!--google adsense ad code-->
          </div>

          </div><!--this is the close of "col2outer"-->



        <div id="footer">{footer}
        </div>

    </div><!--this is the close of "wrapper"-->

    </center>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting `margin-left` and `margin-right` of your content element to the size that your ads need on the left and on the right (should be 240px = .left padding-left + left ad width). You will have to adjust your content width attribute to fit.

Btw you can mess your site up in a normal browser if you don't set it to fullscreen as well.

See [here](http://de.selfhtml.org/navigation/suche/index.htm?Suchanfrage=margin) for a nice picture to the Box Model.

Comment: I tried that, and it sort-of worked. It messed with the size of the content area, and it also made it not properly centered on the page as I liked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative margin as well to shift it off to the left or right (-80px) make you apply some widths as per my example:
http://jsfiddle.net/q7Cf7/

Comment: Unfortunately, that still has the same issue.

Comment: you can add negative positions on absolute elements as well

Comment: All you need to do is put your right and left divs in the main wrap OR content area which ever.  Make sure whichever you choose to place it in has position relative and a width.  Then float left and right with negative margins to position them outside the box.